# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-connection

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I was just following a tutorial online and these errors popped up.

I'm getting the following errors

**Error**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\wisconsindairyfarmers\admin\login.php on line 7

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\wisconsindairyfarmers\admin\login.php on line 7
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'wisconsindairyfarmers');
?>

<?php
require '../db/connect.php';
require '../functions/general.php';

    function user_exists($username){
        //$username = sanitize($username);
        $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM users WHERE UserName = '$username'");
        if($result->num_rows){
        return (mysqli_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
    }}

if(empty($_POST) === false){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){ 
        echo 'You need to enter a username and password';
    }
    else if(user_exists($username) === false) {
        echo 'We can\'t find that username.';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your `$db` variable is inside a function and thus out of scope from the code that defines it. Declare it global, or better, pass it as an argument to your function. See the PHP manual on [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: I changed the variables, and the first error is fixed, but I'm still getting : Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Comment: I think that is because you are using OOP on the first part and procedural for the the results.

Comment: I'm kind of new to php, how do I go about fixing that?

Comment: I think that's because `mysqli_result()` is not a function. I'm really not clear what that piece of code is trying to do, but `mysqli_result()` doesn't exist in PHP.

Comment: It's suppose to check and see if a user exists in a table and if the user does exist it returns a 1. Is there another way to do it with mysqli?

Comment: Is there a mysqli replacement for mysql_result?

Comment: Have you tried: `$result->fetch_assoc()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, you declared $db outside the function. If you want to use it inside the function, you should add it as a another parameter:

```
function user_exists($db, $username){
   ...
```

and than call it like this:

```
user_exists($db, $username)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors anymore, but I can't seem to get into the 'user_exists($username) === false' when I'm testing do you have any other wisdom to share with me today :)

Comment: Yes, your SQL query will always return 1 row, with 1 field saying the amount of users equals to username. Change that to `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = '$username'"` and it will work

Comment: I figured that out, but thank you very much! You've been very helpful! That's what I get for blindly following tutorials

Answer (score 0):

put this line in parent construct : $this->load->database();

```
function  __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('lib_name');
    $model=array('model_name');
    $this->load->model($model);
    $this->load->database();
}
```

this way.. it should work..