# Get all "username" and "id" in MySQL database and split using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL database like this.

```
id........username  
 1 .......rap
 2 .......dafy
 3 .......kay
```

I want to make them like thies

```
username-id,username-id,use...
```

for ex.

```
rap-1,dafy-2,kay-3
```

the code should use the param to prevent the sql injection, but i have no idea how to write code.

Comment: so you just want to fetch all rows and join their id and username together?

Comment: `select concat(username,'-',id) from TABLE`

Comment: yes and the code should use param and the output should be like thies "rap-1,dafy-2,kay-3

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("database","my_user","my_password","my_db");


// Obviously change this to match yours
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(username , '-',id) SEPARATOR ',') as grp FROM table";
$result =  $mysqli->query($sql);
$final_result = []
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    array_push($final_result, $row['grp']);
}


$mysqli -> close();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null......WHY

Comment: did you call your database funtion in a different file? or are you doing it in a funciton

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992830/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-null read that

Comment: in the function you are calling this program. do global $database_variable

Comment: obviously change database_variable to the actual name of the variable

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null....nothing changed

Comment: i just fiexed it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207939/discussion-between-sorax-and-dontbe3greedy).

Answer (score 5):

Use this query for a result:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`username` , '-',`id`) SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table1;
```

Result

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`username` , '-',`id`) SEPARATOR ',')
rap-1,dafy-2,kay-3 .
```

Example PHP code with PDO:

```
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`username` , '-',`id`) SEPARATOR ',') user FROM Table1";
  foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   echo $row['user']."<br />";
  }
  $pdo ->close();
```

Comment: GROUP:CONCAT has also a ORDER  BY option

Comment: I personally like to discover myself and of course i don't know, what you want with this.

Comment: This works, but mind that usernames containing `-` or `,` could break the consumer. Eventually those have to be escaped first. In general if you have access to all consumers a different data format, with a bit more structure, might be wiser.

Comment: @johannes that works also with comma and - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06340e/1

Comment: @nbk yes, it works to produce it but can be hard to parse, again ...